# Is this question about end-grain cuting boards on-topic?

Tags: discussion

My question is what are the advantages and disadvantages of building and using an end-grain cutting board. The answer to this question will require knowledge of woodworking and wood, but may also depend on users who know more about knives and cutting. Is the question on topic?

Answer (score 4):

I would think so.  As wood workers, when we make something, most of the time we need to know about its use in order to build the item to maximize its life and usefulness.

More specialized pieces would require more specialized knowledge.  And experience in building and using them would be collected over time.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to the edit, I don't think it was, because it was too ambiguous as to the intent (with the exception of the last sentence). When it is specifically aimed at "What are the properties of the wood that make it so," then it becomes a question more relevant to woodworking. Really, I think the question being asked is, "What are the properties of endgrain and what should be considered when making an endgrain product?"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is off topic either as long as we stay on topic with woodworking for both the Q and A. My only issue is with your current answer which discusses the effect on kitchen knives

While it is useful information I would think that it should be a foot note in the other current answer which talks about the moisture properties of end grains.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the way it's currently phrased does center it more on the woodworking aspect of the question. Though, as I noted in the comments, I think the portion asking about the difficulties in constructing them is too unrelated and should be it's own question.